# Difference between instance-based and example-based Learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining, labeling, example

I've read both the terms *instance-based* and *example-based* learning in some contexts, e. g. instance-based learning for label ranking and example-based for general text classification tasks.
Is there any difference in the meaning of those two terms or is it just interchangeable?

Comment: Did solve you question with his answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have `instance-based` learning when you don't use the labels so when you use an unsupervised learning and an `example-based` learning when you use a supervised learning that uses both the instance(features) and the label.